# Modify placeholder attribute when radio input is selected

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to update the HTML5 placeholder attribute when the a radio button is selected. I'm not using JQuery, so would prefer an inline JavaScript solution. I know I'm missing something simple, but am trying to teach myself!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ModifyPlaceHolder1 () {
var input = document.getElementById ("MyQuery");
input.placeholder = "Search books e.g. Harry Potter";
}
function ModifyPlaceHolder2 () {
var input = document.getElementById ("MyQuery");
input.placeholder = "Search journals e.g. New Scientist";
}
</script>


<input type="text" id="MyQuery" placeholder="Search resources" name="q" /> 
<input type="radio" value="" id="All" name="s.cmd" checked="checked" />
<label for="All">All</label>
<input type="radio" onclick="ModifyPlaceHolder1 ()" value="" id="Books" name="s.cmd" checked="checked" />
<label for="Books">Books</label>
<input type="radio" onclick="ModifyPlaceHolder2 ()" value="" id="Journals" name="s.cmd" checked="checked" />
<label for="Journals">Journals</label>
```

Comment: Seems to be working fine..? http://jsfiddle.net/dhLfx/

Comment: Technically, it would be better to avoid inline JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do this without any inline JS. A wee bit cleaner, and easier to track (IMO).

```
<input type="text" id="MyQuery" placeholder="Search resources" name="q" /> 
<input type="radio" value="" id="All" name="s.cmd" checked="checked" />
<label for="All">All</label>
<input type="radio" value="" id="Books" name="s.cmd" checked="checked" />
<label for="Books">Books</label>
<input type="radio" value="" id="Journals" name="s.cmd" checked="checked" />
<label for="Journals">Journals</label>

var books = document.getElementById("Books");
var journals = document.getElementById("Journals");
var input = document.getElementById("MyQuery");

books.onclick = function() {
    input.placeholder = "Search books e.g. Harry Potter";
}

journals.onclick = function() {
    input.placeholder = "Search journals e.g. New Scientist";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would program it with a single function as below:

```
<script>
function ModifyPlaceHolder(element) {
  var data = {
    All: 'Search resources',
    Books: 'Search books e.g. Harry Potter',
    Journals: 'Search journals e.g. New Scientist'
  };
  var input = element.form.MyQuery;
  input.placeholder = data[element.id];
}

</script>

<form>
  <input type="text" id="MyQuery" placeholder="Search resources" name="q"> 
  <label for="All"><input type="radio" onclick="ModifyPlaceHolder(this)" id="All" name="s.cmd" checked> All</label>
  <label for="Books"><input type="radio" onclick="ModifyPlaceHolder(this)" id="Books" name="s.cmd"> Books</label>
  <label for="Journals"><input type="radio" onclick="ModifyPlaceHolder(this)" id="Journals" name="s.cmd"> Journals</label>
</form>
```

Note that:

1. Not all browsers in use support the placeholder attribtue
2. Label elements should really wrap the control they apply to, otherwise some browsers won't correctly associate them. Wrapping also means the label acts as part of the button, so clicking on the lable checks the button too.
3. Only one radio button can be checked at a time, so only set one as the default checked.
4. Putting the controls in a form makes them easier to access.

When you see a string of identical listeners that are all contained in one element, you can look to putting a single listener on a parent element. Search for "event delegation".

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<script>
  function ModifyPlaceHolder(element) {
      var data = {
              All: 'Search resources',
              Books: 'Search books e.g. Harry Potter',
              Journals: 'Search journals e.g. New Scientist'
          };
     var input = document.getElementById("MyQuery");
     input.placeholder = data[element.id];
}
</script>
```